# Output line from file1 if not found in file2

Tags: linux, command-line, text-files

I need to output the lines from file1 that are not found in file2, ideally using linux commandline.

Both files are uppercase A-Z, sorted, per-file unique, and contain only one word per line.  Typically, file1 is between 5 and 100 lines long, file2 is 250,000 lines long.  Processing speed is not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -vhFxf file1 file2
```

Works great.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do it for me - seems to print all the lines from file2 even if they appear in file1?

Comment: Ah, wait, the line endings in one of my files is windows. Doh.  Converted now and your grep works fine so long as file2 is first, ie:  grep -vhFxf file2 file1  - thanks.